# What's the groovy one-liner for something like this?

Tags: groovy

I've written the following function that iterates over each element of an array to see it that element is contained within (substring) my test variable called name. I'm sure groovy has a simple way for me to inline this instead of a separate method. Can anyone help?

```
boolean testArray (array, name)  
{       
  for (elem in array)
  {
    if (name.contains (elem))
      return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Groovy, but I doubt there is a shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about :

```
array.any { name.contains it }
```